# Post:all(); displaying only first post - Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
use App\Post;

Route::get('/read',function(){

$posts = Post::all();

foreach($posts as $post){
return $post->title;
}

});
```

Hi, I'm currently following a tutorial on Laravel, and I'm already at the Eloquent part of it. I made 2 posts in my database, posts title are "PHP" and "PHP 2". I was wondering why the first one ("PHP") was the only one showing up. I was expecting both titles to Display. I'm very new to PHP and Laravel btw so I might not understand "deep" terms you might use. Thank you!

Comment: You're returning after your first loop, with the `title` of the post...Try `echo $post->title."<br/>";` instead of `return`.

Comment: Thank you! I was a bit confused with return but now I understand it a bit better.

Comment: All programming language is same.. After `return` is called, all process will be stopped

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the name in the first loop. So, it will return only the first name. Try to use Collection's `implode` function:

```
use App\Post;

Route::get('/read',function(){

    $posts = Post::all();

    return $posts->implode('title', ', ');

});
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections

Comment: Ohh so "return" in my code kinda says = "When I find a hit, I'll exit this loop"?

Comment: No `return` says _return back to the code that called you, immediately_.

Answer (score 0):

to make your code looks good, I think it's better if you split your controller and your route ^^ like:

PostController:

```
use App\Post;

public function getPost() {
   $posts = Post::all();

   foreach($posts as $post) { //if you want to display your post not in view
     echo $post->title;
   }

   // or

   return view('post')->with('posts', $posts); //if you want to display your post in view
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/read', 'PostController@getPost');
```

If you want to show it in view, make a post file:
`post.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  @foreach($posts as $post)
    {{$post->title}}
  @endforeach
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

return is a method for your function which is outside of the foreach loop so  it only runs once and when you call "return" in your foreach loop it will break the loop(because your function for that "return" is outside of the loop) ;
replace it with echo then you can run your loop.

`foreach($posts as $post){ echo $post->title; }`